# Matching elements contained in an array from lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a posts collection as:

```
{
    _id: SOME_ID,
    user: SOME_USER_ID,
    media: SOME_LINK
}
```

and a follow collection as:

```
{
    _id: SOME_ID,
    user: SOME_USER_ID,
    followings: ["SOME_USER_ID"],
    followers: ["SOME_USER_ID"]
}
```

and I want to get posts from users which a given user's followings array contains

I tried this, but no documents were displayed, tried gpt but it says everything is good

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "follows",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "follow",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$follow",
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$follow.followings"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      following: "$follow.followings"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
            $expr: {
        $eq: ["$user", "$following"]
      }
    }
  },
]
```

Comment: your query looks to be fine: https://mongoplayground.net/p/CvnH7qzx4us

Comment: If you post real sample documents then someone might be able to identify the problem. For example, I would guess `SOME_ID` and `SOME_USER_ID` are a mix of strings and `ObjectId` so it's probably failing your last `$match` stage or the first `$lookup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got all the followers list by aggregate pipeline.

```
const follow = await Post.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "follows",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "follow" 
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$follow"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      follow: 1
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  }
])
```

and now searching it in Posts

```
const posts = await Post.find({ user: { $in: follow[0].followings } })
```

posts contains all the posts of the user's following